# Enable MEX in a Web.Config

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

How do I enable/create a MEX endpoint in the below web config so I can view the service from my browser?

I have tried a few variation from googling but VS always complains about it. (not a valid child element etc...)

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
   <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
     <service name="MyApp.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyApp.IMyService"       behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </service>
   </services>
   <behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
       <webHttp/>
     </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

Cheers,
Conor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS, go Tools > WCF Service Configuration Editor.  You can open your web.config and tinker with your WCF endpoints and bindings in a nice GUI that (shouldn't) generate XML that VS will complain about.

Comment: ...or open the tool yourself; on my machine it is located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\SvcConfigEditor.exe`

Comment: Wish I had of know about this tool before, wasted 2 days mucking about with web.configs for the WCF binding, put that down to experience!

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to the web.config right under the service endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MetadataEndpoint"
 contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Thanks josh3736 for the tip on the GUI editor, the only problem I had was I still didn't know how to use the editor to do this, so here is what I did:

1. In VS, open ***Tools/WCF Service Configuration Editor***
2. Open the web.config or app.config file that contains your service definition
3. Navigate to the ***Services / (your service) / Endpoints*** folder
4. If the ***MetadataEndpoint*** is there, click on it and edit the configuration to your liking, otherwise, right-click the ***Endpoint*** folder then click ***New Service Endpoint*** and configure like the one in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add System.ServiceModel.dll under references of your VS Project where your Web.config file is present.

Then add the below code in Web.config(like other service endpoints):

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```