# What's wrong with this URL : Impossible to Add a Service Reference

Tags: soap, visual-studio-2015, wsdl, service-reference

The URL in question:http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatTestService.wsdl

when I click on it with a browser everything seems right but when I want to add a service reference in my project, I have an error message :

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatTestService.wsdl/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. Metadata contains
>   a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatTestService.wsdl'.
>   The content type text/html of the response message does not match the
>   content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If
>   using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method
>   is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:
>   ' 
>   
>        Specific disclaimer for this service ----------------------------------------- 
>        Here is the list of VAT Number to use to receive each kind of answer :       100 = Valid request with Valid VAT Number       200 = Valid
>   request with an Invalid VAT Number        201 = Error : INVALID_INPUT         202
>   = Error : INVALID_REQUESTER_INFO      300 = Error : SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE       301 = Error : MS_UNAVAILABLE        302 = Error : TIMEOUT       400 = Error :
>   VAT_BLOCKED       401 = Error : IP_BLOCKED        500 = Error : GL'. If the
>   service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution
>   and adding the service reference again.

here is this what I receive from a browser (or Postman) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat" xmlns:tns1="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:impl="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
    <xsd:documentation>
     Specific disclaimer for this service ----------------------------------------- 
     Here is the list of VAT Number to use to receive each kind of answer : 
        100 = Valid request with Valid VAT Number
        200 = Valid request with an Invalid VAT Number
        201 = Error : INVALID_INPUT
        202 = Error : INVALID_REQUESTER_INFO
        300 = Error : SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
        301 = Error : MS_UNAVAILABLE
        302 = Error : TIMEOUT
        400 = Error : VAT_BLOCKED
        401 = Error : IP_BLOCKED
        500 = Error : GLOBAL_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ
        501 = Error : GLOBAL_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ_TIME
        600 = Error : MS_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ
        601 = Error : MS_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ_TIME

        For all the other cases, The web service will responds with a "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" error.
    </xsd:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types" xmlns="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">
            <xsd:element name="checkVat">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="countryCode" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="vatNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="checkVatResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="countryCode" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="vatNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="requestDate" type="xsd:date"/>
                        <xsd:element name="valid" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="address" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="checkVatApprox">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="countryCode" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="vatNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderName" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderCompanyType" type="tns1:companyTypeCode"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderStreet" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderPostcode" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderCity" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="requesterCountryCode" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="requesterVatNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="checkVatApproxResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="countryCode" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="vatNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="requestDate" type="xsd:date"/>
                        <xsd:element name="valid" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderCompanyType" nillable="true" type="tns1:companyTypeCode"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderAddress" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderStreet" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderPostcode" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderCity" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderNameMatch" type="tns1:matchCode"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderCompanyTypeMatch" type="tns1:matchCode"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderStreetMatch" type="tns1:matchCode"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderPostcodeMatch" type="tns1:matchCode"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="traderCityMatch" type="tns1:matchCode"/>
                        <xsd:element name="requestIdentifier" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:simpleType name="companyTypeCode">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z]{2}\-[1-9][0-9]?"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="matchCode">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="1">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>VALID</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:enumeration>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="2">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>INVALID</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:enumeration>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="3">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>NOT_PROCESSED</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:enumeration>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="checkVatRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns1:checkVat">
    </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="checkVatApproxResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns1:checkVatApproxResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="checkVatApproxRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns1:checkVatApprox">
    </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="checkVatResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns1:checkVatResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="checkVatPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="checkVat">
            <wsdl:input name="checkVatRequest" message="impl:checkVatRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="checkVatResponse" message="impl:checkVatResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="checkVatApprox">
            <wsdl:input name="checkVatApproxRequest" message="impl:checkVatApproxRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="checkVatApproxResponse" message="impl:checkVatApproxResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="checkVatTestBinding" type="impl:checkVatPortType">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="checkVat">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="checkVatRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="checkVatResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="checkVatApprox">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="checkVatApproxRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="checkVatApproxResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="checkVatTestService">
        <wsdl:port name="checkVatPort" binding="impl:checkVatTestBinding">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatTestService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Is it something's wrong in the URL or in my VS ?

Thank you

Comment: If you are using WCF make sure you have MEX endpoint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754923/enable-mex-in-a-web-config

Comment: I just want to add a service reference by click right on references on the solution explorer then add a service reference and use the url above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the service replies with contentType 'text/html' which confuses the VS service reference tool.

Use the wsdl.exe tool to generate proxy classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make the post to the following address:
http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatTestService

In the bottom part of the message is the URL

```
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatTestService"/>
```